# Баг при добавлении текста

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь добавить текст в текст бокс

```
textBox1.AppendText(answer);
```

при этом переменная string answer не равна null, но вылазит следующая ошибка

> > System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
>
> textBox1 было null.

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Я не знаю что делает AppendText, но может стоит попробовать просто .Text?

Comment: пробовал textBox1.Text = answer; , та же ошибка

Comment: Простите, не углядел сообщение ошибки. Согласен с человеком выше. Посмотрите, что говорит ошибка и танцуйте от этого.

Comment: У меня не равна null переменная

Comment: а вы в коде негде не меняли свойство `Name`??

Comment: `У меня не равна null переменная` ===>  https://i.imgur.com/dqbDnBA.png

Comment: @tym32167, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6024/178988. У меня, например, imgur заблокирован корпоративным файрволлом, а стековский разрешён.

Comment: @Qwertiy все ради вас https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWspW.png

Comment: Как текст бокс может быть равен null если я в него сам вписывал текст? Это какой-то баг

Comment: это вам лучше знать, вы же кода нам никакого не показали

Comment: загрузил на яд весь проект https://yadi.sk/d/CgkeDVlI3aghF4